# How to only read second word on each line Java

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader

until now I have been reading in a file with BufferedReader line by line, however, now I would like to be able to only store the second word on that line. I have my line stored in a hashmap for easy lookup.

```
     int i=0;

     HashMap<Integer, String> mapHash = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file"));
        String st;


        while ((st = in.readLine()) != null) {
            st = st.trim();
            //store the lexicon with position in the hashmap
            mapHash.put(i, st);
            i++;

        }
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
```

Could anyone help me out to only read the second word on each line?

Thanks!

Comment: Use [`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))?

Comment: I suggest using a `List` instead of a `HashMap`.

Comment: I am using the HashMap later on for further lookup and manipulation of the data. To me it seemed the best structure to use and until now it has been fine. What are the advantages in using a List?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

//...
try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file"));) {
        Map<Integer, String> mapHash = new HashMap<>();
        int i = 0;
        String st;

        while ((st = in.readLine()) != null) {
            st = st.trim();
            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(st);
            int j = 0;
            while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                if (j == 1) {
                    mapHash.put(i, tokenizer.nextToken());
                    break;
                } else {
                    tokenizer.nextToken();
                    j++;
                }
            }
            //store the lexicon with position in the hashmap
            i++;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

Comment: This is helping me a lot. But it is still taking up the third word. Would there be a way tell in the buffer reader to go to the nextLine?

Comment: Thanks for that! So, if I decide to read in the third word, I change j == 2? I am still figuring out Java...

Comment: What about if I want to have my HashMap of <Integer, Integer>, because tokenizer.nextToken() is a string, I have been trying to cast it. But no success.

Comment: Use `Integer.valueOf(String s)` method.